# How to add continuous Integration with WindowsAzure?

Tags: unit-testing, azure, github, continuous-integration

Is there a way to add an automatic Test Unit AND deployment solution, using Git/GitHub and WindowsAzure?

On WindowsAzure I use the WebSite And a SQL Server Database.  I Already know how to hook Github for automatic deployement.  But I can't figure how to link some test unit in the process.

Comment: What services are you using?

Comment: @Mlunes tx for the head up.  I just edit my text the anwser you question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki particularly the custom deployments and managing database connections sections.